# Which puppetlabs release package to choose?

Tags: puppet

When looking at http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ there are puppetlabs packages, for the different Debian and Ubuntu releases. But apart from that there is the standard edition (like `puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb`) and the *puppet collection 1* edition (like `puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb`).

**Questions**

- What are the differences ?
- Which version of puppet is supported by the different packages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the PC1 package, i.e. `puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb`.

The `puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb` package is for the Puppet 3 repositories. Puppet 3 goes end-of-life (EOL) at the end of 2016, so shouldn't be installed on new systems. It doesn't contain packages for Ubuntu 16.04 either.

The Puppet Collection 1 (PC1) repositories were created to provide Puppet 4 and the "all-in-one" (AIO) packages, which self-contain all of the dependencies required to run Puppet. You should be using this repository and installing `puppet-agent` for agents and `puppetserver` for the master.

More info:

- [Installing release packages on Apt-based systems](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/install_linux.html#installing-release-packages-on-apt-based-systems), recommends PC1
- [About Puppet Collections and packages](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/puppet_collections.html)